# Perfect makefile

Tags: makefile, build-process, continuous-integration

I'd like to use [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) to get a modular build in combination with [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), *automatic unit testing* and *multi-platform builds*. Similar setups are common in Java and .NET, but I'm having a hard time putting this together for make and C/C++. How can it be achieved?

My requirements:

- fast build;  non-recursive make (Stack Overflow question *[What is your experience with non-recursive make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559216)*)
- modular system (that is, minimal dependencies, makefile in subdirectory with components)
- multiplatform (typically PC for unit testing, embedded target for system integration/release)
- complete dependency checking
- ability to perform (automatic) unit tests (Agile engineering)
- hook into continuous integration system
- easy to use

I've started with [non-rec make](http://code.google.com/p/nonrec-make). I still find it a great place to start.

Limitations so far:

- no integration of unit tests
- incompatibility of windows based ARM compilers with Cygwin paths
- incompatibility of makefile with Windows \ paths
- forward dependencies

My structure looks like:

> ```
>     project_root
>        /algorithm
>                  /src
>                      /algo1.c
>                      /algo2.c
>                  /unit_test
>                      /algo1_test.c
>                      /algo2_test.c
>                  /out
>                      algo1_test.exe
>                      algo1_test.xml
>                      algo2_test.exe
>                      algo2_test.xml
>              headers.h
>        /embunit
>        /harnass
>    makefile
>    Rules.top
> ```

I'd like to keep things simple; here the unit tests (algo1_test.exe) depend on both the 'algorithm' component (ok) and the unit test framework (which may or may not be known at the time of building this). However, moving the build rules to the top make does not appeal to me as this would distribute local knowledge of components throughout the system.

As for the Cygwin paths: I'm working on making the build using relative paths. This resolves the `/cygdrive/c` issue (as compilers can generally handle / paths) without bringing in C: (which make dislikes). Any other ideas?

Comment: Note that you can use `/` as path separator in Windows usually just fine. Nearly every API function that uses paths transparantly translates them to `\` anyway.

Comment: Indeed. However, it's the drive letter which causes problems. Make does not handle the : well (as it defines a target). And that /cygdrive/c/ is not recognized by windows applications. If I translate /cygdrive/c to c:/ then the dependency file generated by a compiler is not recognized by the makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CMake](http://cmake.org/) together with the related tools CTest and CDash seem to answer your requirements. Worth giving it a look.

Bill Hoffman (A lead CMake developer) refers to the [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) paper in a [post](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2004-January/004705.html) at the CMake mailing list:

> ... since cmake is creating the makefiles for you, many of the disadvantages
>   of recursive make are avoided, for example you should not have to debug
>   the makefiles or even think about how they work.   There are other examples
>   of things in that paper that cmake fixes for you as well.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319764/recursive-make-friend-or-foe/320585#320585) for "Recursive Make - friend or foe?" here on stackoverflow.

-
[Recursive Make - friend or foe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319764/recursive-make-friend-or-foe)

Comment: Thanks; I will give this combination a further look. +1 for your effort.

Comment: It's not the answer I was looking for, but I've still accepted it since it may indeed be better to avoid the problem than to solve it in the make files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I do:

I use one Makefile at the root and wildcard patterns to collect **all** files in a directory. Note that I assume that foo/*.c will make up foo.so for example. This makes the maintaining the Makefile minimal, since just adding a file to the directory automatically adds it to the build.

Since it is make you are using I am assuming (I do that for my projects) that a compiler is used that uses gcc (cc) compatible command line syntax. So MSC is out of order; but don't get frustrated, I do most of my development (unfortunately) on Windows and use MinGW with MSys; works like a charm. Produces native binaries, but was built with a Posix compliant build environment.

Dependency checking is done with the somewhat standard `-MD` switch. I then include all the *.d files into the Makefile. I build the patterns out of the automatically collected source files.

Finally unit tests are implemented with the "standard" `check` target. The check target is like the all target, except it depends on the unit test and executes that once everything is built. I do it this way so that you can just build the project or build the unit tests (and the rest of the project) separably. When I am not developing the project I want to just build it and be done with it.

Here is an example of how I do it: https://github.com/rioki/c9y/blob/master/Makefile 
It also has the `install`, `uninstall` and `dist` targets.

As you can see everything is plain make, no recursive make calls and all is relatively simple. I used automake and autoconf and I will never do that again; also other build tools are out of the question, if I need to install foojam or barmake to build something, I normally ditch that project immediately.