# How to compile with a Makefile in sub-directories?

Tags: c, makefile

For a school project I need to create a Makefile that compiles sub-directories without using any other Makefiles. What I mean is that I am not allowed to do this:

```
make -C <sub-folder>
```

Here is how it looks like:

In local:

```
   ./Makefile
   ./sub
   ./sub2
```

And in sub directory:

```
   ./sub/file1.c
   ./sub/file2.c
   ./sub/file3.c
   ./sub/file4.c

   ./sub2/file1.c
   ./sub2/file2.c
   ./sub2/file3.c
   ./sub2/file4.c
```

Here is what I've done so far, but I keep getting errors:

```
CC              =       gcc -W -Wall -Werror

NAME            =       test

NAME2           =       test2

SRCS            =       sub/file1.c            \
                        sub/file2.c            \
                        sub/file3.c            \
                        sub/file4.c

SRCS2           =      sub2/file1.c            \
                        sub2/file2.c            \
                        sub2/file3.c            \
                        sub2/file4.c

OBJS            =       $(SRCS:.c=.o)

OBJS2           =       $(SRCS2:.c=.o)

all:
    $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME)

    $(OBJS2)
    $(CC) $(OBJS2) -o $(NAME2)
```

Thank you, Ephismen.

**[EDIT] Edited my problem**
My problem changed a bit. I need to compile in the same Makefile, always with the same rules, two different binaries. I tried following what worked for one but it doesn't seems to do right for two. If you have any advices please let me know.

The code posted works, but only compiles the first binary.

Comment: Just a thought: `SRCS = sub/file1.c sub/file2.c ...` and remove the `cd`s from the target

Comment: Thank you it worked! But I have a second problem now, I am unable to compile two binaries at the same time without using other makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following (remember to put tabs instead of spaces at beginnings of lines):

```
all: $(NAME) $(NAME2)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME)

$(NAME2): $(OBJS2)
    $(CC) $(OBJS2) -o $(NAME2)
```

Comment: When doing this I get the following error: "Nothing to be done for all".

Comment: @Ephismen This is not an error message; it means `all` (everything) is already made.

Comment: I was doing two mistakes: first the error message i gave you was wrong, second I had one space hidden very far in Makefile so I was wondering where it was comming from. Anyway thank you very much it works perfectly!!

Answer (score 2):

See this article:

[Make Tutorial: How-To Write A Makefile](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/how-to-guides/how-to-write-a-makefile)

It explains everything including why not to use recursive make and how to do includes instead.

You'll especially want to read:  [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) which explains why recursive make is bad and methods for avoiding it.

Comment: Indeed, the [several](http://stackoverflow.com/q/559216/2509) question on Stack Overflow [concerning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/319764/2509) Recursive versus Non-recursive make include links to some well developed make-based build systems.

Comment: This tutorial is not good, e.g. it comes to the following conclusion: _So, you will still need to invoke "make clean" ... about 99% of the time_